# Как включить заголовок на C в файл на C++?

Tags: c, c++

Как включить заголовок на C в файл на C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нужно объявить директиву включения `#include` внутри блока `extern "C"`.

```
// Код на C++

extern "C" {
    // Заголовок на C
    #include "c_header.h"
}

int main() {
    // Вызов функции, объявленной в заголовке на C
    c_function();
}
```